# go-cmp when comparing 2 structs treats empty interface value as int and flat64

Tags: go, reflection

So I am using go-cmp `github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp`. To compare 2 structs.
Both the structs are of same type. When comparing the result I am seeing the following difference.

I am using go v1.12

```
type Sample struct{
   Field1 map[string]interface
}
var a Sample
var b Sample

cmp.Diff(a,b)


// Somewhere in code I do this
a.Field1["sample"] = 1 // this is optional.
```

So if I compare a and b I see the diff where it interprets the same field as int(0) and float64(0)

```
-: int(0)
+: float64(0)
```

I expect the diff to be nil

Comment: FYI in Go there's `struct` and there's `map`, and they are not one and the same thing. So you're not comparing 2 structs but two maps.

Comment: @mkopriva sorry about that, But in my case the map[string]interface is part of a struct I thought of making it simpler.

Comment: How are you populating `a` and `b`? Are you doing `a["sample"] = 1` and `b["sample"] = 1`? Or is one of them unmarshaled from json for example? I'm asking because a json number, even if it represents an integer, is unmarshaled into a `float64` if the destination type is `interface{}` by the `encoding/json` pacakge.

Comment: @ mkopriva well that could be the case. Is there any method I can test this ? 
So I am sending this value from one service to another by marshalling it into json

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/SwXN552p3wl This behaviour is documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal); see the paragraph *"To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value: ..."*

Comment: Thank you this explains and answers my question

Answer (score 0):

As the struct was unmarshalled from json, json treats all numbers as float